# concatenation issue adding static string to dynamic string

Tags: c#

The following code is working fine with the static value `"Application1"`.

```
mailMsg.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", "{ \"category\": [ \"Application1\" ] }");
```

But I want to replace `"Application1"` with a dynamic value.

So I implemented the following code. `Dtls.Category` is the dynamic value.

```
string xsmtpCategory = "{\"category\":\""+Dtls.Category +"\" ] }";
mailMsg.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", xsmtpCategory);
```

But I'm getting the error "not in correct format".

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is the _exact_ value of `Dtls.Category`? Does it contain the quotes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out part of the syntax after the colon:

```
string xsmtpCategory = "{\"category\": [ \""+Dtls.Category +"\" ] }";
```

I would suggest using C# 6.0 string interpolation if possible:

```
mailMsg.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", $@"{{ ""category"": [ ""{Dtls.Category}"" ] }}");
```

Comment: That's c# 6, not 7